# error - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavutil in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I am tryinng to compile `tutorial1.c` for `ffmpeg` available [here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html).

Program returns this error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavutil
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavformat
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavcodec
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavutil
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have followed the instruction given in [this compilation guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) to install `ffmpeg` in ubuntu 15.04.

Command used for compilation:

gcc -I /home/adeshpande/ffmpeg_build/include/ -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm

Answer (score 1):

You could add a -L/path/to/folder/containing/avutil

Comment: No. I have tried the same, but no output. It gives multiple undefined reference. I am getting similar to like https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-October/017981.html

Comment: Hmm.  It's giving undefined references now, but are all the "cannot find" errors gone?